# Ansible - login to heroku

Tags: ansible, heroku-cli

Normally login using terminal is like this

```
sudo heroku login --interactive
Email: My email
Password: My password
Login Successful!
```

this is my role

```
- name: Heroku login
  expect:
    command: heroku login --interactive
    responses:
      (?i)Email: '{{ heroku_email }}'
      (?i)Password: '{{ heroku_password }}'
```

After 30 seconds I got

```
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": "heroku login --interactive", "delta": "0:00:31.545693", "end": "2020-04-02 20:06:40.838040", "msg": "command exceeded timeout", "rc": null, "start": "2020-04-02 20:06:09.292347", "stdout": " \u001b[33m›\u001b[39m   Warning: heroku update available from \u001b[92m7.39.0\u001b[39m to \u001b[92m7.39.2\u001b[39m.\r\nheroku: Enter your login credentials\r\nEmail \u001b[33m[myemail@gmail.com]\u001b[39m: \u001b[2K\u001b[GPassword: ***********", "stdout_lines": [" \u001b[33m›\u001b[39m   Warning: heroku update available from \u001b[92m7.39.0\u001b[39m to \u001b[92m7.39.2\u001b[39m.", "heroku: Enter your login credentials", "Email \u001b[33m[myemail@gmail.com]\u001b[39m: \u001b[2K\u001b[GPassword: ***********"]}
```

Someone have any idea why I got that error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I spent two days doing this, I asked the community anisble but unfortunately it failed. I made an alternative exit, i.e. login using the expect script. It looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

spawn heroku login -i

sleep 1

send "HEROKU_EMAIL";

send "\r"

sleep 1

send "HEROKU_PASSWORD"

sleep 1

send "\r"

sleep 2

interact
```

If anyone wanted the whole role follow the link below

https://github.com/BElluu/Ansible-Heroku-Deploy

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
spawn heroku login -i
expect -re "Email*"
send "EMAIL";
send "\r"
expect -re "Pass*"
send "PASSWORD";
sleep 1
send "\r"
interact
```

Comment: Please consider explaining how and why this solves the problem, so that it can benefit other users.

Answer (score 0):

The default timeout of `expect` module is 30 seconds. From the stdout, it can be seen that expect has responded for both the prompts.

It is possible that the login is taking more than the default timeout. Increase the timeout for the task,

```
- name: Heroku login
  expect:
    command: heroku login --interactive
    responses:
      (?i)Email: '{{ heroku_email }}'
      (?i)Password: '{{ heroku_password }}'
    timeout: 300
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but that's not the problem. I set the timeout value to 300 and I have the same effect. Manual login via terminal takes
maximum two seconds.